# Compute the specific heat capacity of ideal gas under constant $V$ and $p$

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics, statistical-mechanics

> Compute the specific heat capacities at constant volume and constant pressure for air at standard temperature and pressure, assuming it is diatomic ideal gas and a molecular mass of 28u.

I have the equation for an ideal gas : $pV=Nk_BT$

and the caloric equation is : $E=\frac{5}{2}Nk_BT$

Now my definition for heat capacity is: $C=\frac{\delta Q}{dT}$. (Specific heat capacity will this divided by the mass).

Now I get that

$$ C=\frac{\delta Q}{dT}=\frac{dE+pdV}{dT}$$

and

$$C_V=\left(\frac{\partial E}{\partial T} \right)_V \ \ \ \text{,} \ \ \ C_p=\left(\frac{\partial E}{\partial T} \right)_p+p\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T} \right)_p$$

I tried $C_V=\left(\frac{\partial E}{\partial T} \right)_V=\left(\frac{5}{2}Nk_B \right)_V$

but I cannot see how I can proceed with this. Nor do I think $C_p$ will be any easier to use

Comment: don't you know $C_v=(f/2)R,C_p=C_v+R$

Comment: I cannot see that in my notes

Comment: haven't you studied thermodynamics under physics or chemistry?

Comment: no just in maths

Comment: wierd connection: thermodynamics and maths....hmm

Comment: do you know polytropic process??

Comment: Thats definitely not in my course either

Comment: yes that is kinda basic to thermo, do you know enthalphy? internal energy? heat? first law?

Comment: I can see $E=\frac{f}{2}RT$ in my course. yes, yes, yes, yes

Comment: or rather E(t)=E(0)+(f/2)RT, where E_0 is undeterminable.

Comment: I have that $C_p=(\frac{\partial E}{\partial T} )_p +p(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T} )_p$

Comment: In physics it's $q=U+w$ and in chemistry it's $U=q+w$, don't know what it is in maths?

Comment: also U$\sim$E..

Comment: not even in highschool?

Comment: cant remember it.

Comment: see my answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In physics it's $q=\Delta U+w$ and in chemistry it's $\Delta U=q+w$, don't know what it is in maths. but anyways I start with chemistry definition, since every such equation differs only by a sign.

At constant volume, $dV=0$, so $$\Delta W=-pdV=0$$
so $$\Delta Q=\Delta E=\left(\frac{5}{2}\right)Nk_B\Delta T$$
so 
$$C_v=\frac{\partial Q}{\partial T}=\left(\frac{5}{2}\right)Nk_B$$
At constant pressure, $$\Delta H=\Delta E+\Delta (pV)=\Delta Q+\Delta W+pdV=\Delta Q+(-pdV)+pdV=\Delta Q$$
so $$\Delta Q=\Delta H=\Delta E+\Delta(pV)=\left(\frac{5}{2}\right)Nk_B\Delta T+\underbrace{Nk_B\Delta T}_{\text{actually it's }\Delta(Nk_BT) }=\left(\frac{5}{2}+1\right)Nk_BT$$, so $$C_p=\frac{\partial Q}{\partial T}=\left(\frac{5}{2}+1\right)Nk_B$$

Comment: $\Delta E = \Delta Q + \Delta W$, Q heat, W work done, E internal energy?

Comment: @1234 yes here, delta E is delta U, delta Q is q and delta W is w

Comment: Why are you using deltas when this is a question about something stable?

Comment: @1234 if you give heat and are trying to characterise it using heat capacity... then a change is bound to happen

Comment: When are we "giving" heat?

Comment: @1234 if you want to measure the rate of change of heat wrt temperature i.e. $C=\partial Q/\partial T$ you need to change tempertaure and then if heat doesn't change so $C=0$ otherwise $C\ne0$ and heat is exchanged